# Understanding the Hubble relation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, space-expansion

The Hubble relation is

$z = \dfrac{H_0}{c}r$

which simplifies to

$v = H_0r$.

But how can this be, if

$z \neq v/c$

at relativistic speeds? Hubble uses a linear relation for galaxies moving up to 1000 km/s in his original paper, and more recent work by Freedman et al. goes out to 2000 km/s. Speeds like that are certainly in the relativistic domain. So, why is the relation still linear out to those speeds??

Answer (score 3):

The Hubble relation is
$$ v = H D,$$
where $D$ is the proper distance and $v$ is the rate of change of proper distance.

To convert this to a relationship with redshift requires knowledge of the cosmological parameters and only works in the way you have suggested for small redshifts, where indeed  $z \simeq v/c$.

It does not work for redshifts that are anything near 1 or above, since cosmological redshift is *not a Doppler effect due to relative motion*.

This paper by [Davis & Lineweaver (2003)](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808) is well worth looking at. Here is the very relevant plot from that paper showing the correct way to view the relationship between velocity and redshift.

[image: Plot from Davis & Lineweaver]

Comment: Thanks very much for the paper recommendation, looks like a good one to have on hand

Comment: Can you further explain this; "cosmological redshift is not a Doppler effect due to relative motion."?

Comment: That is almost the entire subject of the paper referred to @jphollowed . The expansion of space causes the redshift. Galaxies etc. have relatively small velocities with respect to the comoving reference frame.